# React js workflow, how to handle dynamic children at the parent level

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I may be missing a core tenant of React here, but at a high level I a flex layout something like the code below (stripped out the browser specific flex variants for brevity). I am starting with what I'd like to end up with conceptually:

```
 body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .box {
      height: 100vh;
      max-height: 100vh;
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .boxHeader, .boxFooter {
      flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
    boxContent {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      overflow-Y: auto;
    }
```

I am trying to get a basic page layout like this:

```
<div className="box">
  <div className="boxHeader" id='coreHeader>
    <HeaderComponentOne>Some Content - header is pseudo-fixed</HeaderComponentOne>
  </div>
  <div className="boxHeader id="dynamicHeader">
    <HeaderComponentTwo>Some Content - header is pseudo-fixed</HeaderComponentTwo>
  </div>
  <div className="boxContent>
    {this.props.children}
  </main>
  <div className="boxFooter" id="dynamicFooter>
    <FooterComponentOne>Some Content - footer is pseudo-fixed</FooterComponentOne>
  </div>
  <div className="boxFooter" id="coreFooter">
    <HeaderComponentTwo>Some Content - footer is pseudo-fixed</FooterComponentTwo>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is all good and works - except that I need the dynamic header a footer to remain pseudo-fixed, but the content to be provided dynamically based on the current child 'page'. So it's almost like I somehow need to pass the child's props to the parent layout's dynamic header and footer. I don't care whether it ends up being a parent or child/children, but the flex layout will choke if other surrounding divs or elements are stuck in the middle of it, so 'wrappers' do not seem like an option.

Again this is conceptually what I'd like to end up with and am open to pretty much anything that gets me there. I am not even sure what to try next to get this end effect. I've played with several parent child combinations trying to get this to behave as expected and spent hours searching for something similar to no avail. Can something like this even be done and if so, what are the suggestions or thoughts on how best to approach it? I am also using react router is that matters.

[Here](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JXByVg) is a codepen that shows the basic need, but the issue is that these must be stacked on top of each other with no extraneous React wrapping div's in the mix and such since that seems to throw flex off. I also need two of these to sometimes not be on the page and that seems to mess flex up too.

So - in essence get 2 React dynamic header components - the 2nd of which may not always be there, one or more dynamic React content components that scroll as needed, and two dynamic React footer components - the 1st of which may not always be there to behave like the codepen. Headers and footers are 'fixed' and content scrolls.

I am guessing there has to be some way to make the two play nice together, but maybe not and if so I haven't figured it out yet.

TIA!

Comment: It is not really clear (to me) what you are trying to accomplish here. What do you mean by "pseudo-fixed"? Could you share a picture or fiddle of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: With flex, elements are 'fixed' with flex: 0,0 - but do not have the position set to fixed like with CSS. Wanted to distinguish that to avoid replies saying set the position to fixed. I am adding a codepen to the question that shows the basic need, but the issue is that react add additional wrapping div's and such and that throws flex off.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed each react component can only render one component, so each react component will at least need a wrapper.
But your structure has handcoded all the `<div>` wrappers, and you do not these those.

To get react to render the structure you want, your root react component would render something like:

```
<div className="container">
  <HeaderComponentOne>Some Content</HeaderComponentOne>
  <HeaderComponentTwo>Some Content</HeaderComponentTwo>
  {this.props.children}
  </main>
  <FooterComponentOne>Some Content</FooterComponentOne>
  <FooterComponentTwo>Some Content</FooterComponentTwo>
</div>
```

Each of the subcomponents (`<HeaderComponentOne>` andsoforth, as well as each of the `this.props.children`) can also only render one component, possibly rendering other/ multiple sub-sub-components. But this is fine with your structure.
You would simply need to apply the applicable classNames to each of those components.

You can find a [working react-based codepen here](http://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/WwgRWv?editors=0010).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks... I had been pretty much down that path but the issue I run into is getting the props passed to the various components in the layout because they are typically driven by the children in the content. I am currently looking into Redux as a possible solution where the children could update the redux state and then layout components could read it on render. That just seems like a lot to get a (normally) simple layout to work as expected.

Comment: Well, if the layout of the headers and footers depend on some props of children, then you should not pass those as props to children, but to the root component.